# HTML5 Canvas switch content by clicking on tabs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm doing one simple project on HTML5 Canvas. I want to have a few tabs in my canvas, for example let's take 4 tabs. All these tabs should display some information in the "active content" area (see picture below). Different content from different tabs will be shown.

This is what I want it to look like, very simple and basic:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWfhA.png]

How can I switch the content when clicking on the different tabs in the canvas?

Comment: I simply have drawn a couple of rectangle, that's all. Also I'm doing research on KinecticJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas do not have native support for drawing with content as everything is just pixels on a bitmap so to get this sort of behavior with canvas you will have to implement the basic logic yourself.

I would recommend an object based approach. Create your tabs as objects which then allows you to render them but also testing them for hits, and it's easy to expand number of tabs etc.

### [Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/pDM93/)

An object can be very simple:

```
var Tab = function(x, y, width, height, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.lineWidth = 3;
};
```

then add a method to build the path for the rectangle and to render it, which is simply:

```
var Tab = function(x, y, width, height, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.lineWidth = 3;

    /// creates a new path on the context
    this.getPath = function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };

    /// draws this tab
    this.render = function(ctx) {
        this.getPath(ctx);
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        ctx.stroke();
    };
};
```

The purpose of this is to use it for rendering it as well as hit-test it.

Now you can create a few tabs:

```
var myTabs = [
        new Tab(0, 0, 100, 50, 'blue'),
        new Tab(100, 0, 100, 50, 'red'),
        new Tab(200, 0, 100, 50, 'yellow'),
        new Tab(300, 0, 100, 50, 'orange'),
    ];
```

Now simply render them:

```
for(var i = 0, tab; tab = myTabs[i++];)
    tab.render(ctx);
```

To hit test:

```
for(var i = 0, tab; tab = myTabs[i++];) {
    tab.getPath(ctx);
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
        // got a hit, update content
    }
}
```

I'll leave it to you to extend the `Tab` object with ability to accept and render text and so forth :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, for your effort, I appreciate that. I will try to go deeper, because I have a great plans for this tabs. I want to make a simple game for kids. What for example I need to do to implement and style text inside this tabs area?

Comment: @user3340575 no problem! Just add those as properties, f.ex `this.text`, then add code in the render method to draw them specifically for that tab - the code here will determine how the text will look for a tab. All the tabs will have this reflected and you don't even need to change your other code.

Comment: @user3340575 to show the first or main tab just refactor the code a bit so you have a f.ex `showContent(tab)` method. which you can call initially with the tab you want to display first. Then call it again in the loop checking for clicks. In the method render the content for current tab (tip: you could add a this.id property to the tab object).

Comment: I got the idea, but I not able to do it. Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Content could be drawn basing on a state variable. You can use a switch statement to do so. Then you change the state variable's value when the user clicks on the tabs.
To detect clicks on tabs, you can bind an onclick event to the canvas, and in the event handler you check where the click was (i.e. on which tab it was) and set the state variable accordingly.

Comment: Can you please provide small example on js fiddle?